# How do i refresh the datacontext on page

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am using MVVM in WP8 app. I have a landing page(`AllProducts.xaml`) which displays a list of Products. In constructor i have `this.DataContext = productsViewModel;`

In `AllProducts.xaml`, i have a

1. `listbox` bind to a property(`ProductList`) of `productsViewModel`.
2. an app bar with ADD button which takes user to `AddProduct.xaml` page. Here, the user adds a new product which gets saved in database. After the save method is called, I have  `NavigationService.GoBack();` which takes user to previous page (`AllProducts.xaml`)

However, the `AllProducts.xaml` does now shows the newly added product. This is obvious & i think it is because of `NavigationService.GoBack();` which just restores the state of previous page and does not rebinds it.

How do i rebind/refresh the page so that the newly added  product is displayed in list?

Here is the xaml code in `AllProducts.xaml` which is bound to a `ProductList` property of `productsViewModel`

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding GetProductList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Name="lls"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateHere}"
                        toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" 
                        SelectionChanged="lls_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Here is my `productsViewModel`

```
    public class productsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private ObservableCollection<ProductList> _productList;
            public ObservableCollection<ProductList> GetProductList
            {
                get
                {
                    var prodList = from p in unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetAll()
                                  join c in unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll()
                                  on p.CustId equals c.CustId
                                  select new ProductList { ProductId = p.Id, ProductName = p.ProductName, CustomerId = c.CustId};
                    _productList= new ObservableCollection<ProductList>(prodList .ToList());
                    return _productList;
                }
                set
                {
                    _productList= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GetProductList");
                }
            }


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my ProductList class.

```
 public class ProductList
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string  ProductName { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you gotta let the binding know that it needs to query the getter..
so after adding the new item

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => productsViewModel);

or make productsViewModel an ObservableCollection
```

Comment: But the user adds new Product/item in AddProduct.xaml page. After he is done saving, i make him go back to AllProducts.xaml page. Here i dont see the newly added item.  How do i let kick the databinding of AllProducts.xaml again ?

Can you explain where do i need to call RaisePropertyChanged(() => productsViewModel); and how ?

Comment: raising property changed will "kick/re-query the binding". if you don't know how to raise property changed, look up the interface INotifiyPropertyChanged. Make your viewmodel implement it. then raise it for the property that you want the binding to re-query

Comment: perfect! raise it when you need the binding to respond :)\

Comment: just gotta let the binding know that you what you have changed. when and how is in your hands, the rest of the posts below, as I am reading, are trying to guide, help you just in that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class productsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      private IEnumerable<Product> _productList;
public IEnumerable<Product> ProductList
{
    get
    {
        return _productList;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_productList!= value)
        {
            _productList= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ProductList");
        }
    }
}
       ......

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try use in your view: protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           //update your model here
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Using an ObservableCollection should already handle any changes to the list, anything bound to my list "ProductsList" below will automatically update in the UI. Note that your DataContext is MainViewModel and "ProductsList" is the ItemsSource of the listbox.

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.ProductsList = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Products> ProductsList { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```